# how to link crtbegin.o and crtend.o to my 32-bit OS with clang

Tags: linker, operating-system, crt

Lately I've been toying around with making an x86 OS, and decided to convert it from using a GCC cross compiler to using `clang`. Specifically, I made the Makefile use `clang -target i386-pc-none` and `-m32`. After some fighting, I finally managed to make it past the compile stage and into the linking stage, however I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `arch/i386/crtbegin.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `arch/i386/crtend.o' is incompatible with i386 output
```

Note that both of these files are actually non-existent on my OS and are just put there at some point during the build process by the compiler (I specifically tell it to do so in the Makefile). However, even though I have `-m32` and the `-target` flags and also have a 32-bit libc installed (My OS is 64-bit, though), it doesn't try to link the 32 bit versions. How can I fix this?

Should the system crtbegin and crtend even be used? It's very late, I can't think at all.

All help is appreciated and I can provide more info along with source if needed, thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you try to link with crt? If you are making an OS, you don't need to link with crt.

Comment: Actually you could just tell the linker what's your entry point. I don't know about clang. With ld just specify the entry point with ```-entry main```. That'll tell ld to make the entry point of the executable the ```main``` function.

Comment: @user123 The OS at some point jumps to C code. My problem right now is that with i686-elf-gcc it used to create some compatible crtbegin and crtend files that worked great with it, but now with `clang` they are not compatible, and I don't know why. I'd suppose perhaps it gets something with the target architecture wrong but I believe `i386-pc-none` is correct. But perhaps it tries to generate a 64-bit crt despite `-m32`. I really don't know what's going on and why just a compiler change broke so much stuff.

Comment: @user123 Looking at it a bit more, it indeed seems that it tries to get a 64-bit crtbegin and crtend whereas i686-elf-gcc has the correct 32-bit versions

Comment: Honestly, I don't know much about c runtime and stuff like that. I thought that in a freestanding implementation there is none of that. Isn't crtbegin and crtend used to call constructors and destructors of objects. In a freestanding and static OS there is no need to do that. What is there to construct and destroy? Have you passed the ```-nostdlibs``` flag to clang and the ```-ffreestanding``` flag?

Comment: You say in the question that you have a 32 bits libc installed. Did you write your own system call interface in your OS to actually respond to calls in libc. What version of libc do you have? Libc is operating-system dependent. It means that it does system calls in the OS to respond to requests in user code. Basically, unless you wrote a full system call interface for libc in your OS (which I doubt), you can't link to stdlib or anything. Actually, if you are writing an OS (not a user application targeting your OS), you should always pass the -nostdlibs and -ffreestanding flags.

Comment: @user123 I indeed never passed `-nostdlibs` to clang. Also I have no system call interface. Will test `-nostdlibs` later, not on my computer currently. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about clang's flags. It must be something similar. Basically, you gotta tell your compiler not to use the standard library (and not use it in code).